# How can I easily create this matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can I easily create the following matrix in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)?

With A (nxn), B (nxp) and N a positive integer.

```
Gamma = [B         0         0         ...   0 ; 
         A*B       B         0         ...   0 ; 
         A^2*B     A*B       B         ...   0 ; 
         ...       ...       ...       ... ... ; 
         A^(N-1)*B A^(N-2)*B A^(N-3)*B ...   B];
```

Comment: BTW, naming an array Gamma is a somewhat bad idea, as while it should not conflict directly with the function gamma because of the capital letter, it still can be dangerous. (When you are debugging code, or reading it afterwards, etc.) I'd suggest trying to stay away from name conflicts with existing/useful functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, though it is less efficient than it could be.

```
n = size(A,1);
p = size(B,2);

N = 3;
Gamma = zeros(N*n, N*p);

for ii = 1:N
  for jj = 1:N
    if ii >= jj
      Gamma((ii-1)*n+1:ii*n,(jj-1)*p+1:jj*p) = A^(ii-jj) * B;
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit:** Here's a more efficient version, that does the minimum amount of matrix multiplication.

```
n = size(A,1);
p = size(A,2);

N = 3;
Gamma = zeros(N*n, N*p);

# Pre-compute all the matrix multiplications we'll need.
memo = cell(1, N);
memo{1} = B;
for ii = 1:N-1
  memo{ii+1} = A * memo{ii};
end

for ii = 1:N
  for jj = 1:N
    if ii >= jj
      Gamma((ii-1)*n+1:ii*n,(jj-1)*p+1:jj*p) = memo{ii-jj+1};
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
[g{1:N,1:N}] = deal( zeros(n,p) );
g{1,1} = B;
for ii = 2:N
    g( ii, 2:end ) = g( ii-1, 1:end-1 );
    g{ ii, 1 } = A * g{ ii-1, 1 };
end
Gamma = cell2mat( g );
```

Comment: @Shai Did you run this code? It invokes errors. For instance, `A` is a matrix and `g(..)` is a cell, and you attempt to multiply them.

Comment: I've fixed one other bug, for the size of the zero upper triangular cells. Otherwise, the cell2mat call at the end would have had problems, since B was explicitly n by p, not n by n.